# im Haus, in Berlin, im Duden

Tags: noun

There are three sentences. Here is the first one:

> 1. Laura ist in dem Haus. (Laura ist im Haus.)

*Das Haus* has a neuter grammatical gender, dative case is used, so it is *im*. That is the rule.

Here is the second sentence:

> 2. Johannes ist in Berlin.

*Berlin* has also neuter grammatical gender. The way I understand it, proper nouns do not change the article *in* into *im* in the dative case (if they have neuter or masculine grammatical gender). That would probably be an exception to the already mentioned rule.

Here is the third sentence:

> 3. Es gibt keinen Eintrag „pragerisch“ im Duden.

*Duden* is a proper noun. According to [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Duden) it has a masculine grammatical gender. (Duden doesn't have an entry for the word *Duden*, but it has probably really the masculine grammatical gender). The word *Duden* is a proper noun, and because of it there should be *in Duden*.

I am thinking of three possible explanations:

i) The word *Duden* is an exception of the exception.

ii) Proper nouns having masculine grammatical gender do have the *im* preposition in dative case.

iii) The sentence 3. is wrong and there should be *in Duden*.

Could you please help me to figure out the situation?

Thank you.

Comment: It is simply wrong to assume that all proper nouns don't have an article. Rivers, for example, have articles.

Comment: I just yesterday read [this paper](https://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/files/2018/06/N%C3%BCbling-2015-classifier-ZGL.pdf), which should anwer all your questions, and even the ones you didn't yet think of.

Comment: The rules dealing with articles of proper nouns are not only complicated, there are even regional differences: In Standard German names of people are used without articles (*"Lisa ist krank. Hast du Lukas gesehen?"*). But in southern regions (Bavaria, Austria) you use articles for names of persons in colloquial speech: *"Die Lisa ist krank. Hast du den Lukas gesehen?"* You do it also with surnames, for example in this title of a famous novel and movie: [Der Bockerer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Bockerer)

Answer (score 4):

It's none of the three explanations offered, but another one: In German, books that are considered a standard reference in their field are often referred to by *the author's name* (or *the editor's name*). Thus, they are typically used with an article, for example:

- *der Beutelspacher* (a Linear Algebra book by Albert Beutelspacher)
- *der Fischer* (a law commentary by Thomas Fischer)
- *der Duden* (a dictionary by Konrad Duden)

The following examples show how the Duden is used with different cases:

> - *Der Duden* steht im Regal.
> - Die Seiten *des Dudens* sind eingerissen.
> - Ich lerne mit *dem Duden*.
> - Ich habe Kaffe auf *den Duden* geschüttet.
> - Es gibt keinen Eintrag ***im*** Duden (= ***in dem*** Duden).

Answer (score 4):

Your three examples are exactly the same in English. Not that that explains the German, but if you are a native English speaker it may help intuitively understand it.

*„Laura ist im Haus“* - Laura is in the house. You would not say *'Laura is in house'*

*„Johannes ist in Berlin“* - Johannes is in Berlin. You would not say *'Johannes is in the Berlin'*  Only for those small number of places which take an article like *'the Netherlands'* which anyway takes an article in German *„die Niederlande“*

*„Es gibt keinen Eintrag 'pragerisch' im Duden.“* - I won't translate that but it is correct to say in English *'Look that up in the Britannica'* or *'You can't find that word in the Oxford'* Acutally, it would be wrong to say *'You can't find that word in Oxford'*, it sounds maybe like you are talking about the town Oxford rather than the Oxford Dictionary

I am not sure if you can universally apply this between the languages but for those three examples it seems to hold.

Comment: In order to clarify and confuse at the same time, I'd like to add the phrase: "Im Berlin der 20er Jahre.....". In this phrase you do combine "im" with the name of a place/city, which alters the meaning to "Berlin in the 1920's...."

Answer (score -1):

You basically gave the right answer in your first example. Just as "Laura ist *im* Haus" is the shorter and more usual form of "Laura ist *in dem* Haus", "Es steht *im* Duden" stands for "Es steht *in dem* Duden". Note that "dem" is used in Dativ for both male or neutral nouns so even with the neutral "Wörterbuch" the sentence would be the same "Es steht *im* Wörterbuch" and only in case of a female noun we could not use that abbreviation "Es steht nicht *in der* Enzyklopädie".

Comment: Could the downvoter give me a hint on what to improve? Did I mix something up? Am I rude without noticing it? Is there any doubt that this answer is correct?

Comment: No down-vote from me, but your answer seems to talk about what *im* means, whereas OP asked about when an article is used with proper nouns.